# Button switch change default color

Tags: ios, uiswitch

How can I change the color of the UISwitch Button? When it appears in the simulator, it shouldn't be in `On`, but in `Off`. I want to see it in white color, and when active, it should become green.

Answer (score 5):

You can have access to the onTintColor and tintColor property of the UISwitchView.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *onTintColor
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor
```

When initializing your switch, set the onTintColor for the color you want for On value and tintColor for Off value.
For instance in a UIViewController:

```
    UISwitch *theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 41.0, 30.0)];

    // on color
    theSwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    //off color
    theSwitch.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:theSwitch];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler for changing the switch value (see below). Also don't forget to set the initial color, depending on the state of the switch.

```
- (void)onFlipSwitch:(UISwitch *)aSwitch {
    if(aSwitch.on) {
        aSwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else {
        aSwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```